# Prove the given identity

Tags: trigonometry

$ \dfrac{2\sin x}{\cos 3x}  +  \dfrac{2\sin 3x}{\cos 9x}  + \dfrac{2\sin 9x}{\cos 27x} = \tan 27 x- \tan x$.

I did not get even to start with which formula. I tried using multiple angle identities but did not find any suitable place to use those. So please help.

Comment: The question already exists

Comment: @ Archis where does it exist? I haven't posted it before

Comment: There are many people who ask questions please see tags.

Answer (score 1):

See if [this](http://www.sosmath.com/trig/prodform/prodform.html) leads you anywhere. I've included an example for your first term:

$\dfrac{2\sin x}{\cos3x} = \dfrac{\dfrac{2\sin x\cos x}{\cos x}}{\cos3x} = \dfrac{2\sin x\cos x}{\cos x \times \cos3x} = \dfrac{2\sin x\cos x}{\dfrac{1}{2}(\cos4x + \cos2x)}$

One advantage of this is you may be able to begin condensing using the double angle formula. Also note that they're all in multiples of 3, i.e $x$ and $3x$, $3x$ and $9x$, etc. so a few substitutions may help.

EDIT: OP, I'd recommend you to take a look at the answers on this post when it was previously asked i.e [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299957/show-that-frac-sin-x-cos-3x-frac-sin-3x-cos-9x-frac-sin-9x). Particularly Lab Bhatacharjee's post is simple and insightful, although I myself am not yet familiar with telescoping series (I am a sophomore in high school). Also, if you'd like an inductive approach, take a look at Leg's answer.